# Compute height of a triangle in a circular segment

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

I am computing some lengths and angles in a circular segment and found an interesting example in the following link on page 25:

http://www.qucosa.de/fileadmin/data/qucosa/documents/18871/Geod%C3%A4tische%20Berechnungen_2015.pdf

It is clear how to compute $h$ and $s$ but I don't understand the formula for $y$. Which theorem I have to use in order to prove this result?

Comment: Please include all relevant information and definitions in your question. Many users here do not read German, and if the link expires, your question will be entirely meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct right triangle in the following way:
[image]

Then $h-y$ defines the value of that small line (arrow pointer show it), then using Pythagorean theorem we get: $r-(h-y)=\sqrt {MP^2-(\tfrac{s}{2}-x)^2}=\sqrt {r^2-(\tfrac{s}{2}-x)^2}$. And, finally: $$y=\sqrt {r^2-(\tfrac{s}{2}-x)^2}-r+h$$

Comment: Great thank you for the illustration!